# magento not updating from 1.8 to 1.8.1.0

Tags: magento

My store is running on 1.8.0.0 and I tried to run the below code via ssh to upgrade to 1.8.1.0 but it stayed at 1.8.0.0. I ran the below commands on one of my stores that had magento 1.7 and it worked and upgraded to 1.8.1.0

1. "chmod 777 mage"
2. "./mage sync"
3. "./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force"
4. "rm -rf downloader/pearlib/cache/* downloader/pearlib/download/*"
5. "find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;"
6. "find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;"
7. delete var folder

Comment: what was the output when you ran above

Comment: @user3093979 follow this instruction to upgrade http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-upgrade-roadmap?icid=BLOG_magentoce1810release_upgradeinstructions